# Extends another model from another module issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, extensions, overrides, model, third-party-module

This is the model which I want to overwrite:

```
class Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Model_Newsletter_Sub extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
{
    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {
        if (Mage::helper('ddg')->isNewsletterSuccessDisabled($this->getStoreId())) {
            return $this;
        } else {
            parent::sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it is declared in the config.xml , the models:

```
...
<models>
    <ddg_automation>
        <class>Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>email_connector_resource</resourceModel>
    </ddg_automation>
....
```

This is my try:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <ddg_automation>
            <rewrite>
                <model>Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Newsletter_Sub</model>
            </rewrite>
        </ddg_automation>
.....
```

The the model:

```
class Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Newsletter_Sub extends Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Model_Newsletter_Sub
{
    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {
        parent::sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();
    }
}
```

and the settings:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Aschroder_SMTPPro>
            <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Dotdigitalgroup_Email/>
            </depends>
       </Aschroder_SMTPPro>
    </modules>
</config>
```

It always gets to `Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Model_Newsletter_Sub` instead of  `Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Newsletter_Sub`. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config.xml model rewrite seems wrong, try

```
<models>
    <smtppro>
        <rewrite>
            <SMTPPRO_MODEL_YOUR_WANT_TO_REWRITE>Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Model_Newsletter_Sub</SMTPPRO_MODEL_YOUR_WANT_TO_REWRITE>
        </rewrite>
    </smtppro>
<models>
```

Also this seems not to be correct in your model:

```
class Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Newsletter_Sub extends Dotdigitalgroup_Email_Model_Newsletter_Sub
```

Please add an link to this extension.